# Android WebView - onTouchListener stop working after scrolling page

Tags: android, webview, scroll, touch-event, ontouchlistener

I'm working on an application that shows images (like a slide show), when the user touches the image I want to open a web page in a WebView.

The problem that I have is how to monitor user activity?

For example, if a user no longer view the web site, don't touch it, scroll or zoom for 15 seconds I want to return to the slide show.

I'm trying to onTouchListener and onTouch method that works until I scrolled the page (when I touch the screen it calls three times - respectively event=ACTION_DOWN/ ACTION_MOVE/ ACTION_UP), when you touch the screen to scroll a page, it is called up twice (event=ACTION_DOWN/ACTION_MOVE) and onTouchListener method no longer works. Then I touch the screen multiple times and onTouch never call again.

Part of the code where I set WebView properties:

```
private void setWebViewProperties() {

    mWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView);
    mWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
    mWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    mWebView.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
    mWebView.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            noWebTouchActive = false;
            mHandler.postDelayed(noWebActive, 10000);
            return false;
        }
    });
    mWebView.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
}
```

Any ideas how I can properly recognize user gestures and monitor his activity?

Comment: possible duplicate of [android: ZoomPicker breaks onTouchListener](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4529093/android-zoompicker-breaks-ontouchlistener)

Answer (score 3):

I think it's a bug.
Look here:

https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?can=2&start=0&num=100&q=&colspec=ID%20Type%20Status%20Owner%20Summary%20Stars&groupby=&sort=&id=36713

I resolved in this way disabling the BuiltInZoomControls

```
mWebView.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(false)
```